# Best way to have this complex horizontal as well as vertical scrolling structure in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am working on my app which is having this kind of structure. [See image](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMJq5Rt0ZwxTS3FGHHpCeFBwZcALj3ARrVurdi7DKVbGsYuOOOCmKdwTdvCdiowog?key=Ym9NRmx4U0pMZlhtS0ZXdVM3WDhZZERhcVlCY1pR).

This is showing details for one vehicle listing, but there is also horizontal scrolling so on swiping next it should load next listing. Also each listing has pull to refresh feature. Images can also be swiped next to load more images. The "Overview", "Details" are different tabs and each load their respective details when clicked. User can also scroll up and be able to see more details underneath.

What is the best possible approach to have this kind of structure in my app? Which UI components I should use and how? Also there are thousands of listing, so we wouldn't load all the views at once to avoid memory issues. But if we are reusing views in horizontal layout there is also chance that horizontal scrolling is not smooth and lags when changing pages due to the complex view structure in each page? Has anyone came across this kind of view structure and has solution to do this?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The best way to acheive horizontal scrolling of views is to use SwipeView (https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView) because it has view reusability feature

Comment: This question is way to broad and potentially primarily opinion-based, since you ask for the "best way" to accomplish this behavior.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal `UICollectionView` as the root

- Each `UICollectionViewCell` contains a detail `UIViewController`

Each detail `UIViewController` contains a `UITableView`

- `UITableView` contains the pull to refresh
- Each `UITableViewCell` is a different section of the detail screen (image gallery, tabs, overview)

Each image gallery `UITableViewCell` contains a `UICollectionView`

- Each `UICollectionViewCell` contains each image

This biggest performance related issue will be to make sure that all of the above view hierarchy is only constructed once, not in each cell reuse. All of the above components should be injectable with your model objects or view models that will populate them. Each reuse will simply change the values being displayed and reload the associated `UICollectionView`s and `UITableView`s.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using UICollectionView and UITableView with multiple sections inside each UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UIPageViewController` with two viewcontrollers so you can display alternatively with different data. Second thing you can take `scrollview` in both view controller which can scroll vertically.

So when you swipe horizontally it change pages with new data and if you swipe vertically it will scroll vertically.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Page view controller is a nicer way to do this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use `UIPageViewController` for Horizontal scrolling and `UITableView` for vertical scrolling in each child `UIViewController` of `UIPageViewController`.

This way I can further segregate it by using another horizontal scrollview inside `UITableViewCells` if I want.

Please don't use plain `UIScrollView` for either Horizontal or Vertical scrolling as these are heavy and memory management is hard to achieve manually.

Hope it helps. Cheers!